# Why are the json fields returned from Autodesk Forge API for displayName different for "included" and "data" fields?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

When querying a model (item) via the Autodesk Data Management Forge API:

`GET projects/​:project_id/​folders/​:folder_id/​search`

the returned `data.attributes.displayName` is sometimes different than the `included.attributes.displayName` for the same id.  Can you explain what the difference is between "included" and "data" and which would be the one to use to get the current value of the name that is displayed in the A360 Project.

Example with the names changed and pertinent data only:

```
{
    "jsonapi": {
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    "links": {
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "type": "versions",
            "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.00UeaES1TmW67ZUDMfSn1A?version=3",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "56750_A.rvt",
                "displayName": "56750_A.rvt",
                }
            }       
        }
    ],
    "included": [
        {
            "type": "items",
            "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:00UeaES1TmW67ZUDMfSn1A",
            "attributes": {
                "displayName": "343435_A.rvt",

            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you add a sample response from SEARCH and the other (which one)?

Comment: Added example response to original message